# My php project has file which I never create and it keep growing what could I do?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, security, oscommerce

I'm taking care of a legacy php oscommerce project and I found a file that I didn't create called "imagers.php". The content of the file is showing below. The file is being written and the size keeps growing. Which area should I start looking into?

```
QUERY select code, title, symbol_left, symbol_right, decimal_point, thousands_point, decimal_places, value from currencies
RESULT Resource id #21 
QUERY select languages_id, name, code, image, directory from languages order by sort_order
RESULT Resource id #27 
QUERY delete from whos_online where time_last_click < '1686056585'
RESULT 1 
QUERY select count(*) as count from whos_online where session_id = 'bgsj8nm84fqg8g4eul131dshu0'
RESULT Resource id #35 
QUERY insert into whos_online (customer_id, full_name, session_id, ip_address, time_entry, time_last_click, last_page_url) values ('0', 'Guest', 'bgsj8nm84fqg8g4eul131dshu0', '', '1686057485', '1686057485', '')
RESULT 1 
QUERY select banners_id, date_scheduled from banners where date_scheduled != ''
RESULT Resource id #45 
QUERY select b.banners_id, b.expires_date, b.expires_impressions, sum(bh.banners_shown) as banners_shown from banners b, banners_history bh where b.status = '1' and b.banners_id = bh.banners_id group by b.banners_id
RESULT Resource id #48 
QUERY select specials_id from specials where status = '1' and now() >= expires_date and expires_date > 0
RESULT Resource id #52 
QUERY select information_id, headline from information_db where status='1' order by sort_order
RESULT Resource id #61 
QUERY select c.categories_id, cd.categories_name, c.parent_id from categories c, categories_description cd where c.parent_id = '0' and c.categories_id != '17' and c.categories_id = cd.categories_id and cd.language_id='4' order by sort_order, cd.categories_name
RESULT Resource id #64 
QUERY select count(*) as total from products p, products_to_categories p2c where p.products_id = p2c.products_id and p.products_status = '1' and p2c.categories_id = '90'
RESULT Resource id #67 
QUERY select categories_id from categories where parent_id = '90'
RESULT Resource id #70 
QUERY select count(*) as total from products p, products_to_categories p2c where p.products_id = p2c.products_id and p.products_status = '1' and p2c.categories_id = '91'
RESULT Resource id #73 
QUERY select categories_id from categories where parent_id = '91'
RESULT Resource id #76 
QUERY select count(*) as total from products p, products_to_categories p2c where p.products_id = p2c.products_id and p.products_status = '1' and p2c.categories_id = '92'
RESULT Resource id #79 
QUERY select categories_id from categories where parent_id = '92'
RESULT Resource id #82
```

I've checked the access_log and it was no action on access_log while the imagers.php is still growing. How could I stop this? and what is happening on my website.

Comment: it looks like something is writing SQL logs in there. search the whole project for that file as a string and you'll see where it's used

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), see [ask].